# What is the difference between an "issue of covenant" and an "abomination to God"?

Tags: mosaic-law, exegesis

When looking at Old Testament Mosaic law, I'm confused as to what applies to Christians and what does not.  In an [answer to a previous question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/19508/4412) that I asked, it was said that a certain law did "not seem to be an issue of covenant, but an actual abomination to God."  Are an "issue of covenant" and an "abomination to God" different categories of laws in the Old Testament?  What is the Christian view of how different types of Mosaic law apply to us?

Answer (score 4):

They are not different categories of laws, the answerer of your other question is referring to the exact text of the verse

> "is an abomination to the Lord your God"

and then combining it with the fact that God is

> the same yesterday today and forever (Hebrews 13:8)

so it is not a matter of covenant, which we were freed from through Jesus, but rather of Gods "preference" (so to speak) which do not change

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @gideonmarx I'm not really sure how I can expand this answer without being needlessly wordy, if there is something you would like me to elaborate on, I will gladly do so